# box shadow element into button tag

Tags: html, css

Shadows work properly on all elements, on IE and Firefox, but not for the button element in Chrome and Safari:

http://jsfiddle.net/q8xaa/

```
<button class="btn-test">
<span class="btn">test</span>
</button>


.btn-test {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
.btn-test:hover .btn {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-test .btn {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #000;

    background-color: #f00;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: visible;

}
```

Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: why not put the styles directly onto `btn-test` - http://jsfiddle.net/q8xaa/3/?

Comment: @Pete because I need to put multiple elements inside that button: http://jsfiddle.net/H23Jy/2/

Comment: Ah, I would use Fabrizio's method then but change your hover to be on the button: http://jsfiddle.net/H23Jy/4/

Answer (score 2):

> **Example** http://jsfiddle.net/H23Jy/1/

I tried forcing a zero CSS3 transformation as shown below

**CSS**

```
button span {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

and the shadow seems to work fine also on Chrome 35.

But as you can see, in that way the button is not vertically aligned with the other buttons, so you could use `-webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);` instead

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: looks like we can use any ZERO transform like `translateX(0)`, `rotate(0)`, `scale(1,1)`, ...

Comment: Nice. It seems that Chrome is collecting bugs :/

Comment: nice one, it's not a resolutive solution but it's a big step ahead... ty! http://jsfiddle.net/H23Jy/11/

Comment: why have you used the transform with other vendors prefixes? this is needed just for webkit